# Diffuculty with implementing smooth scroll with Macaw

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this smooth scroll jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

How can I make it work with `window.location` button? I'm stuck. Here's the button:

```
<button onClick="window.location='#services';" class="_button">services</button>
```

Comment: Can you amend the HTML of that button?

Comment: The html is there...?

Comment: I know, I'm asking if you have the ability to *change* the HTML

Comment: No, since Macaw creates the HTML automatically. That's why I'm trying to figure out how to implement window.location buttons with that Jquery instead of 'a'

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your `<button>` element to an anchor `<a>` so that you can use a proper href instead of the onClick. Once you change the element to an anchor you can set the href in the Advanced palette in the Inspector. You can still style it to look like a button with :hover and :active states.

Comment: I think he also wanted to know how to animate links transition